# submitting the selected checkbox items in array of objects using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

As i am working on a feature where the functionality is if the user selects either single checkbox or multiple checkboxes then based on the selection those values should submit to the form. For that i have written the below functionality. Please have a look at the code and let me know why the code is not working for me. As i am sending the selected checkbox values as array of objects.

Here in the code in one like it shows the error as "type void is not assignable to type any[]"

Can anybody help me out to figure it out.

My html template code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
    <div class="box1 box-default">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class=" box-default">
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 w-100" matSort *ngIf="apiAccounts.length != 0">
                    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                                [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                                [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()" color="primary">
                            </mat-checkbox>
                        </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" color="primary">
                            </mat-checkbox>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <!-- Position Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.apiName}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- Name Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Stage </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stage}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- Stage Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="stage">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Region </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.region}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            <h3 class="text-center text-primary" *ngIf="apiAccounts.length === 0"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-raised-button class="color-primary">Register</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

The json data will come in this format:

```
{
  "requestId": "None",
  "requestTime": "2020-04-02T09:48:39.927+0000",
  "errors": false,
  "messages": [],
  "data": [
    {
      "apiId": "a967w4ckzk",
      "apiName": "Point of Sale System Documentation",
      "stage": "env",
      "region": "us-east-1"
    },
    {
      "apiId": "w8a0mkjogc",
      "apiName": "Swagger Petstore",
      "stage": "prod",
      "region": "us-east-1"
    },
    {
      "apiId": "w8a0mkjogc",
      "apiName": "Swagger Petstore",
      "stage": "prod",
      "region": "us-east-1"
    },
    {
      "apiId": "9hxehyfn60",
      "apiName": "PetStore",
      "stage": "dev",
      "region": "us-west-1"
    },
    {
      "apiId": "iu65o649i0",
      "apiName": "PetStore",
      "stage": "dev",
      "region": "us-west-1"
    }
  ],
  "totalPages": 0,
  "totalElements": 0
}
```

The component code is below:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  stage: string;
  region: string;
}


export class CloudAPIGatewayComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['select','position', 'name', 'stage'];
  dataSource = null;
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);
  apiAccounts: Array<Account> = [];
  apiId;
  form: FormGroup;
  ordersData = [];
  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
  constructor(
    private apiGatewayService: ApigatewayService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
       orders: new FormArray([])
      });
      // async orders
    of(this.getApiGatewayAccounts()).subscribe(orders => {
      this.ordersData = orders;
      this.addCheckboxes();
    });
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiId = this.data;
    this.getApiGatewayAccounts();
  }
  getApiGatewayAccounts() {
    this.handler.activateLoader();
    this.apiGatewayService.getAllApisGateway(this.apiId).subscribe(
      results => {
        this.handler.hideLoader();
        if (this.handler.handle(results)) {
          return;
        }
        this.apiAccounts = results['data'];
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.apiAccounts);
      },
      error => {
        this.handler.hideLoader();
        this.handler.error(error);
      }
    );
  }

  private addCheckboxes() {
    this.apiAccounts.forEach((o, i) => {
      const control = new FormControl(i === 0); // if first item set to true, else false
      (this.form.controls.orders as FormArray).push(control);
   });
  }
  submit() {
    const selectedOrderIds = this.form.value.orders
      .map((v, i) => v ? this.apiAccounts[i].id : null)
      .filter(v => v !== null);
    console.log(selectedOrderIds);
  }
}
```

When i select any checkbox to submit its values then the array shows empty. No value is passed.

[image]

See what i can in the console on submitting.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would go an easier route without the formGroup since you're not using any other inputs.

You have the [SelectionModel](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/collections/selection-model.ts) already in there. Then you are inserting and removing the checkbox values, when the change event happens `(change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"` It's in the HTML of the component.

Toggle() toggles a value between selected and deselected.

You can remove the formGroup and some dependent functions on those and just submit `this.selection.selected`

And voila, this should work. Removing all the code for building the forms. Then you have a clean code except the `forEache`s. These can be removed and use `map` instead

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-with-selection-model-example)

Comment: Could you please provide me example or stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-with-selection-model-example it's without Angular Material but the principle is the same.